# THT (Tetrahydrothiophene) absorption spectrum

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, chemical-compounds, quantum-chemistry

I am looking for the absorption spectrum of THT. What is the best way to find these types of exotic material's spectral characteristics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good source of spectroscopic data is the [NIST Chemistry WebBook](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/). It compiles all possible information about polyatomic molecules including their UV/Vis and IR spectra. You will find references to corresponding papers and, as I see, the new version includes a Java applet that plots the UV spectrum. Here is a direct link to [THT spectrum](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C110010&Mask=400#UV-Vis-Spec).

Comment: I checked and cannot see the IR spectrum. Is there any other source I can go and look at. Google doesn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: @Frank: Google is usually not very useful in finding scientific papers, it is better to use a specialized search engine like Web of Science. However, if you try  alternative names of THT (see NIST page), then even with Google you will succeed with a query "Thiacyclopentane infrared" leading to  J. R. Durig et al, “Microwave, Infrared and Raman Spectra of 
Thiacyclopentane,” J. Mol. Struct., 142, 53 (1986). Probably, you'll need to go to a library to get this paper.